# Add pattern to an array without push()

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to code this without using any methods?

a is an array, n is the number of times the pattern is repeated in the new array

```
const func = (a, n) => {

  const arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    arr.push(...a);

  }

  console.log(arr);

};

func([1, 2, 3, 4], 2);
```

Comment: you mean without .push() method ?

Comment: yeah, i mean is there a way to code this function without using any array methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a separate index and assign the values.

```js
const func = (a, n) => {
    let array = [],
        i = 0;

    while (n--) for (const v of a) array[i++] = v;

    return array;
};

console.log(...func([1, 2, 3, 4], 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the spread operator to create a new array for each iteration of the loop. This would mean that your `arr` variable can't be a constant though since it gets overwritten with a new array.

```js
const func = (a, n) => {

  let arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    arr = [...arr, ...a];

  }

  console.log(arr);

};

func([1, 2, 3, 4], 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use two loops and directly assign `i`th array item.

```js
const func = (a, n) => {

  const arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
      arr[i * a.length + j] = a[j]
    }
  }

  console.log(arr);

};

func([1, 2, 3, 4], 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

that ?

```js
const func=(a, n)=>
  {
  const arr = []
  let   p = 0
  for (let i=0;i<n;++i) for(let v of a) arr[p++] = v
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
  }

func([1, 2, 3, 4], 2);
```